# Кнопка в нав. панели в стадии прокрутки

Tags: css, навигация

Здравствуйте! Немного запутался...

Есть навигационная панель в шапке сайта, у которой 2 стадии:

- Пассивная ( при загрузке )
- После прокрутки ( см. unbounce.com )

В шапке помимо стандартных ссылок "Главная", "Услуги" должна быть кнопка заказа, которая появится только в стадии прокрутки.

Как такое сделать?

.nav .scrolled {
?
}

Грубо говоря, копия unbounce.com

Добавить в html навигационной панели эту ссылку и делать её видимой только в .nav .scrolled ?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Готовое решение https://codyhouse.co/gem/secondary-fixed-navigation/, попробуйте адаптировать под себя.